# C++ opencv method is slower than python

Tags: python, c++, performance, opencv

Trying to use opencv with c++. C++ Function cvtColor works 16 times slower than on python.
I created c++ and python programs to test efficiency of cvtColor function.
The cvtcolor s return same values on python and c++. Python cycle runs 650-750 times per second. C++ do it 25-35 times. How to fix it?
I have already tried opencv 4.5.3 and 4.2.0 for c++.

python :

```
frame = cv2.imread(path)
fps = 0
clock = time.perf_counter()
while clock + 10 > time.perf_counter():
    fps += 1/10
    res = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
print(fps)
```

c++ :

```
Mat frame, frame_HSV;
frame = imread(path);
frame_HSV = frame.clone();
int fps = 0;
unsigned __int64 clock_ = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
unsigned __int64 now;
clock_t start, end;
while (true) {
    fps += 1;
    now = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    if (now - clock_ > 1000) {
        clock_ = now;
        cout << fps << endl;
        fps = 0;
    }
    cvtColor(frame, frame_HSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
}
```

Comment: Did you install opencv python via a package manager and compiled opencv c++ yourself?

Comment: Don't print inside the loop. You're not measuring the same thing.

Comment: you need to provide a "minimal reproducible example", which includes the picture file. further, you are comparing DIFFERENT versions of OpenCV (4.2 and 4.5).

Comment: Compilation flags (mainly for OpenCV) also matters a lot. If one version is running in parallel or use the GPU as opposed to the other, then having a huge difference in performance is totally legit. Check the resource usage to compare both and find such a problem.

Comment: 1) No, i did not compilled it by myself. 2) I am printing fps every second, not every iteration in c++ code. 3) I am using 4.4.0.44 opencv for python and tried 4.2.0 and 4.5.3 for c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some problem with your approach. I cannot point it out correctly but I am showing how I did it and my results.

###### Python

(Version: 4.5.1, IDE: VS Code)

```py
import cv2
import time as t

img = cv2.imread("18JE0646.jpg")
t1 = t.time()

for _ in range(10000):
    hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

t2 = t.time()
print(t2-t1)
```

Output: 10.5 sec

##### C++

(Version: 4.5.2, IDE: Visual Studio 2019 (Release Mode))

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    cv::Mat img, hsvImg;
    img = cv::imread("18JE0646.jpg");
    time_t start, finish;
    
    time(&start);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; i++)
        cv::cvtColor(img, hsvImg, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    time(&finish);
    cout << difftime(finish, start) << " sec";
    return 0;
}
```

Output: 4.4 sec

#### NOTE:

In C++, check the mode (Debug/Release) before running your code especially if you are computing the time taken by your algorithm. The Debug mode is about 40-50 times slower than the Release mode.
The above C++ code took 4.4 sec in Release mode and 237 sec in Debug mode.

Comment: Thank you for this exapmles. It prooves again that something is wrong. My reuslts: python - 13 sec, c++ - 322 sec.

Comment: @MrIce Read the NOTE I have added just now in my answer. That can be the issue.